# ActionView::Template::Error ("javascript file" isn't precompiled)

Tags: javascript, jquery, activeadmin, web-deployment, jplayer

```
    Started GET "/admin/login" for 81.21.138.77 at 2013-03-13 16:30:57 +0100
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /u/apps/arbinet/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/app/views/active_admin/devise/shared/_links.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /u/apps/arbinet/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.5.0/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/active_admin_logged_out (142.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 150ms

ActionView::Template::Error (jquery.jplayer.min.js isn't precompiled):
    9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag style.path, style.options %>
    10:   <% end %>
    11:   <% ActiveAdmin.application.javascripts.each do |path| %>
    12:     <%= javascript_include_tag path %>
    13:   <% end %>
    14: 
    15:   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:142:in `digest_for'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:150:in `rewrite_asset_path'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/asset_paths.rb:27:in `compute_public_path'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:56:in `asset_path'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:32:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `collect'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `javascript_include_tag'
  activeadmin (0.5.0) app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb:12:in `block in __u_apps_arbinet_shared_bundle_ruby_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_layouts_active_admin_logged_out_html_erb__2231755831832575965_32663520'
  activeadmin (0.5.0) app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb:11:in `each'
  activeadmin (0.5.0) app/views/layouts/active_admin_logged_out.html.erb:11:in `__u_apps_arbinet_shared_bundle_ruby_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_layouts_active_admin_logged_out_html_erb__2231755831832575965_32663520'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
```

When I deploy the project I got this:

```
 ** [out :: web.arbinet.eu] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: web.arbinet.eu] couldn't find file 'swfobject'
```

I already tried this:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and this: `config.assets.precompile += %w(jquery.jplayer.min.js)`
Both in production

And also I made this from the terminal: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Without succes :(!

Here is my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery-ui
//= require swfobject
//=require jquery-ui.min
```

And the application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

Any idea? I need help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the `jquery.jplayer.min` in `application.js` via `//= require jquery.jplayer.min`. I think there is no need to precompile the file.